# Insert into post button missing on custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, uploads, media

I have just purchased a theme called **HQ Photography** from themeforest which has a custom post type called `gallery`.

I can add images from my hard drive no problem - but if I click the media tab and select an image the 'Insert into post button' is missing

I found a site which suggested I needed to add a custom filter to functions.php

```
add_filter('get_media_item_args', 'force_send_to_post'); 

function force_send_to_post($vars) { 
    $vars['send'] = true; // 'send' as in "Send to Editor" 
    return($vars); 
}
```

This brings the button back but the button then does nothing.

Does anyone one know what could be wrong?

**UPDATE:** It seams the above function does work! - **however** only for images that are 'unattached' - once an image has been 'attached' the insert into post does nothing

Can you attach images to multiple posts?

Comment: Is there in your theme looks like "media_send_to_editor" ? (I belive best in this case will be contact theme author and ask him what's going on).

Comment: I guess im looking in javascript for this? or PHP?

Comment: Think I'd be happy to pay someone to fix this for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like theme author disabled this fuctionality for certian post type's attachments, for a reason. Trying to get it back could very well break something else. Try contacting theme's author. (S)he will probably provide free support.

Comment: I found this plugin http://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/duplicate-images - which allows you to 'attach' existing images to my custom post types - tested it and it seams to work ok